# Detect connection leaks with FindBugs

Tags: java, findbugs

I am trying to use FindBugs to detect connection leaks, but it fails to do so in the following two cases.

#### Scenario 1

```
    public static int getSeq(Integer id) throws FatalException {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = null;
        int commentSeq = 0;
        try {
            con = JDBCUtil.getConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(GET_NEXT_COMMENT_ID);
            pstmt.setInt(1, id.intValue());

            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                commentSeq = new Integer(rs.getInt(1)).intValue();
                return commentSeq;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logError("getNextId", e);
        } finally {
            close(rs, pstmt);
        }
        return commentSeq;
    }
```

#### Scenario 2

```
public void someMethod() {
    con = JDBCUtil.getConnection();
    doSomethingWithDb(con);
    //No Closing of the connection, but findbug does not complain
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine it's because it's never heard of your `JDBCUtil` class before, and isn't setup to consider it an opener of JDBC connections.

Comment: Not to derail this but, does FindBugs fail to warn about boxing and unboxing of Integer?